# Need to split something dynamically from a string

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string which is somewhat like this:

```
string data = "I have a {apple} and a {orange}";
```

I need to extract the content inside `{}`, let's say for 10 times

I tried this

```
string[] split = data.Split(new char[] { '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The problem is my data is going to be dynamic and I wouldn't know at what instance the `{<>}` would be present, it can also be something like this

```
Give {Pen} {Pencil}
```

I guess the above method wouldn't work, so I would really like to know a dynamic way to do this. Any input would be really helpful.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: How about [regex](https://regex101.com/r/rOzZtI/1)?

Comment: As much as you see it used when it shouldn't be, regex does have some legit uses, give it a go

Comment: @Fildor yea but i'm not sure how to use it,im kinda new to C#

Comment: @musefan yea but how would i be able to store the data ,like just the data of {} seperately??

Comment: @Venky: There are more C# regex tutorials on the internet than there are grains of sand in the whole world... there are also plenty of false facts on the internet too. Although, it seems some people are willing to do the work for you anyway, so you're in luck...

Comment: @Fildor: Did you know, there are more ways to store data than there are grains of sand in the whole world...

Comment: @musefan You really are into that grains of sand analogy, aren't you? ;D

Comment: @Fildor: One day I hope to have used it in more comments than there are grains of whole rice in the world... or maybe I will have forgotten it by tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string between `{}` does not contain nested `{}` you can use a regex to perform this task:

```
string data = "I have a {apple} and a {orange}";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\{(?<Name>[A-z0-9]*)\}");
var matches = reg.Matches(data);
foreach (var m in matches.OfType<Match>())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Found {m.Groups["Name"].Value} at {m.Index}");
}
```

To replace the strings between `{}` you can use `Regex.Replace`:

```
reg.Replace(data, m => m.Groups["Name"].Value + "_")
// Will produce "I have a apple_ and a orange_"
```

To get the rest of the string, you can use `Regex.Split`:

```
Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"\{[A-z0-9]*\}");
var result = reg2.Split(data);
// will contain "I have a ", " and a ", "", you might want to remove ""
```

Comment: How would i be able to store the rest of the data,apart from the {} ones??

Comment: What do mean "rest of the data" ? @Venky

Comment: Like, {} ones in a seperate array may be and then the normal ones in a seperate array,eg "apple","orange" and "I have a" and "and a"

Comment: You can retrieve the rest of the data by splitting based on m.Index. If you want to replace the data between `{}` you can use `reg.Replace(data, m => m.Groups["Name"].Value + "_")`

Comment: Nope dont want to replace,just need to store {} ones and normal ones seperately thats all

Comment: @Venky ok, added code to get the rest of the string

Comment: @Venky and how would you know the order of those strings if they will be in separate array? I mean which one goes after which.

Comment: @Evk yea,i'll have to figure something out for that

Comment: @Venky Forgot about regex.Split, will do exactly what you want. Updated the answer

Comment: This is almost working ,except for one thing,what should i do to make this work in cases like {a computer},where a space is introduced inside the brackets

Comment: @Venky you need to adjust the regex: `new Regex(@"\{[A-z0-9\s]*\}")`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
string data = "I have a {apple} and a {orange}";
Regex rx = new Regex("{(.*?)}");

foreach (Match item in rx.Matches(data))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

You need to use `Regex` to get all values you need.

Comment: How would i be able to store the rest of the data,apart from the {} ones??

Comment: @Venky not sure I got you, give me an example

Comment: Like, {} ones in a seperate array may be and then the normal ones in a seperate array,eg "apple","orange" and "I have a" and "and a"

Comment: Stores the values you get in an array or a list then use substring to split your string to do what you need.

Comment: @Venky: Why would you want to do that? I feel you haven't told us your true requirement... are you perhaps trying to rebuild the string with different values? Like a replace function?

Comment: No,i work on Xamarin Apps,and i want the {} one to be appended in an EditText and the others on a TextView,thats all,thats the reason i mentioned splitting

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to split that string into parts like this:

```
I have a 
{apple} 
 and a 
{orange}
```

And then you want to go over those parts and do something with them, and that something is different depending on whether part is enclosed in `{}` or not. If so - you need `Regex.Split`:

```
string data = "I have a {apple} and a {orange}";
var parts = Regex.Split(data, @"({.*?})");            
foreach (var part in parts) {
    if (part.StartsWith("{") && part.EndsWith("}")) {
        var trimmed = part.TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}');
        // "apple" and "orange" go here
        // do something with {} part
    }
    else {
        // "I have a " and " and a " go here
        // do something with other part
    }
}
```